# App is not working in aab format download from Play Store, but works fine in APK downloaded from App bundle

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, google-play-console, android-app-bundle

Some of the app functionality is not working when downloaded from the Play Store, it was in AAB format when uploaded.

This is the error when using the app download from the Play Store.
[image: AAB Error]

It works fine in the apk(same version with aab) that was downloaded from the app bundle. Not sure what's going on?

Comment: have you tested it with release apk file ?

Comment: @Pratik Fagadiya I did, the apk(Same version with uploaded AAB) I download from App bundle from Google Play Console is working fine [Offline install], but it did not work properly when download directly from Play Store. That's weird.

Comment: @TIM you using any POJO / MODEL / OKHTTP / Retrofit class library in your App??

Comment: @MDEV we have several 3rd party SDK in the project, so you are suspecting these?

Comment: @TIM Check your build.gradle (:app) enabled `minifyEnabled true` & `shrinkResources true` or not? And please give some more about your app. Like you using custom API to fetch resources or data or FireBase?

Comment: I suspect you're using an SDK with which you need to register the certificate of your app but you registered your upload certificate instead of your production release certificate (you can find it in the Play Console). But not enough info to confirm this is the issue

Comment: MDEV Pierre Thanks for the heads up, will look into this 2 first